# C char to byte comparison

Tags: c, arrays, xcode, char, byte

I'm trying to compare the following:

```
static const char ADDR = 0xF1;
```

and

`buffer[1]` which is UInt8[256] with the value f1 at index 1

So they should be equal but in my test they came as different:

```
if (bufferReceived[1] != PC_ADDR)
```

What would be a best practice in converting the data types so my comparison will come out as correct.

Comment: Is `PC_ADDR` the same as `ADDR`? How is `bufferReceived` declared?

Comment: PC_ADDR is f1 and ADDR is 0xF1. In c# after comparing them, they came up as equal, but not in Objective-C.

Comment: Is PC_ADDR `0xF1` though? You say that PC_ADDR is 'f1' but that does not necessarily mean it is `0xF1`.  Are you sure it is not represented as a `char *` when you view it in a debugger?